# How to parse nested JSON Array in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an array like below which I want to parse. 
I need to display the `flight_details` and `fare_details` but I can't get any values from it. I created JSONobject for "data" and both flight and fare details based on data object. How do I solve this?

```
{
"tag":"Flight Search Results",
"success":"1",
"xml_filename":"dom_one_20150604172653.xml",
"data":[ {"depart_from_location":"Bangalore",
"depart_from_location_code":"BLR",
"depart_to_location":"Calicut",
"depart_to_location_code":"CCJ",
       "departure_details":[{
        "id":"0001",
         "flight_details":[
           {
            "airline_name":"Air India",
           ------------------------
         }],
         "fare_details":{
         "base_fare":"7301",
         "airport_tax":"5365",
         "service_tax":"46",
         "transaction_charge":"0",
         "total":"12962",
         "total_amount":"12962.00"
         }
         },
         {
          "id":"0002"
           "flight_details":[
           {
            "airline_name":"Air India",
           ------------------------
         }],
         "fare_details":{
         "base_fare":"7301",
         "airport_tax":"5365",
         "service_tax":"46",
         "transaction_charge":"0",
         "total":"12962",
         "total_amount":"12962.00"
         }
         }
         ]
}
```

My code

```
   private void json_parser(JSONArray jarray){
    try {

        flight_list=new ArrayList<Flight>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject flight_details = object.getJSONObject("flight_details");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   flight_details.getString("airline_name").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   flight_list.add(new Flight(object.getString("depart_from_location_code"),       object.getString("depart_to_location_code")));

        }
```

Comment: Search on _Google_. for demo tutorial

Comment: Please let us know....what prob are you facing in this?

Comment: Can you Post the URL for this

Comment: "http://gaadiready.com/flight_api/getFlightSearchResults/?key=PPSYrvnMnS&trip_type=domestic&flight_mode=ONE&from=Bangalore/BLR&to=Calicut/CCJ
&depart_date=15-06-2015&return_date=&no_adult=2&no_child=2&no_infant=1&cabin_type=E"
this is the url we are using. When I try to create object for flight_details the app stops forcefully

Answer (score 1):

flight_details is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. You have not given your complete code but the extraction would roughly look like this.

```
JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
// flight details is a JSONArray
JSONArray flight_details = object.getJSONArray("flight_details");
for (int j = 0; j < flight_details.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject object = flight_details.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.d("Airline Name: ", object.getString("airline_name"));
}
// fare details is a JSONObject
JSONObject fare_details= object.getJSONObject("fare_details");
Log.d("Base fare", fare_details.getString("base_fare"));
Log.d("Airport tax", fare_details.getString("airport_tax"));
....
```

Comment: tryed it but getting an error like this: @json_parser﹕ No value for flight_details

Comment: You have already parsed the `departure_details` right? What are you passing inside the json_parser method?

Comment: Thank you sir, i got it... i spend almost 2 days for this issue... thank you so much....

Answer (score 0):

Read it carefully before use and also you have to do some changes as per you response.[Android JSON parsing using Volley]

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Answer (score 0):

correct code:

```
  private void json_parser(JSONArray jarray){
    try {

        flight_list=new ArrayList<Flight>();
      boarding_points=new ArrayList<Seat_Search>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("departure_details");
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject departure_details = array.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray flarray = departure_details.getJSONArray("flight_details");
                for(int k = 0;k< flarray.length(); k++){
                    JSONObject flight_details = flarray.getJSONObject(k);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), flight_details.getString("airline_name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }

        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("@json_parser", e.getMessage());
     }
    }
```